# How do i make this into rounded extrusion in the first go?

Tags: modeling

[image: Required]

Link for the Video:
https://youtu.be/g0UEIeX8Mvo

I'm new to blender. Is there an easy way to round the edge rather than g for extrude and ctrl b for rounding edge? It seems extrusion is coming off very sharply near edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subdivision surface modifier to achieve this result, but beveling wouldn't be a problem

On the left, the mesh has a subdivision surface modifier and on the right I just gave it the shape with bevels and added a bevel modifier on top to make the edges less sharp

1- without modifiers

[image]

2- with modifiers on

[image]

Comment: Thank you, there are so many ways, it just gets mixed up sometimes.